# Mini blackjack game

Tags: php

Im working in a mini game in PHP but i have problem for distribute dealer cards

I have 2 variable for dealer

```
$bank[0] = ace +11 // its the total of cards with ace = 11
$bank[1] = ace +1 // total with ace = 1

$stay = false;
if ($bank[0] == $bank[1]) {
    if ($bank[0] >= 17) {
        $stay = true;
    }
} 
else {
    if ($bank[1] >= 17) {
        $stay = true;
    } 
    else {
        if ($bank[0] >= 17 && $bank[0] <= 21) {
            $stay = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Example for dealer with this script i have 5 cards "6 + ACE(1) + 2 + 4 + 6" = 19 
but me i need script stop with 3 cards like this "6 + ACE(11) + 2" = 19
Thanks

Comment: Are the first 2 lines actual code that your running or is it just there to show whats in the two banks?

Comment: Yes is just for show `[0]` is ace with value +11 and `[1]` is +1 for "6 + ACE + 2" `$bank[0] = 19` and `$bank[1] = 9`

Comment: The logic could be simplified some but otherwise it looks ok. I'm assuming that this ran within a loop, are you adding 11 for the ace on every iteration?

Comment: I have tested many change but not working fine. Yes i incremente for each card with value +1 and +11

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$stay = false;
//it doesn't matter if $bank[0] == $bank[1]
if ($bank[0] >= 17 && $bank[0] <=21) {
    $stay = true;
}
else {
    if ($bank[1] >= 17 && $bank[1] <=21) {
        $stay = true;
    }
    else{
        if ($bank[0] > 21 && $bank[1] > 21) {
            //The bank lost
        }
        else{
            //stay is already false, as declared above
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: $bank[0] and $bank[1] is same if not Ace in the hand but if Ace this value is not identic example if i have "6 and Ace" $bank = 7, 17 (not identic) but if hand is "6 and 2" $bank = 8, 8 (identic)